# User input via cin.getline

Tags: c++, c++14

I wrote a code where user is asked to input a line of text up to 132 characters (Array size is 133 for \0 at the end of the array).

I have used while loop to catch if the user did not input anything and hit return.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const short SIZE = 133;

int main()
{
    char InputArray[SIZE];
    cout << "Enter a line of text up to 132 characters: " << endl;
    cin.getline(InputArray, SIZE);
    count = strlen(InputArray);

    while (count == 0)
    {
        cout << "You did not enter any entry! Try again." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter a line of text up to 132 characters.: " << endl;
        cin.getline(InputArray, SIZE);
        count = strlen(InputArray);
    }

cout << "You had entered: " << InputArray << endl;
cout << "The character count was: " << count << endl;

system ('pause');

return 0;
}
```

How can I catch the user if they go over the size of the array? and generate a text of message saying user input was invalid and ask them to cin.getline again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `get` function. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get). This will read only as much input as you want.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr size_t numberOfBytes = 6;

int main() {

    std::cout << "\nPlease enter up to " << numberOfBytes-1 << " characters:  ";
    char data[numberOfBytes];
    std::cin.get(data, numberOfBytes);

    std::cout << "\nEntered: " << data << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to read any number of charcters and then check the size afterwards, then use a `std::string`. You should do anyway.

So:

```
std::string s{};
std::cin >> s;
if (s.length() > ....) {
....
}
```